# Why EnumMap assign a Object class object for null values?

Tags: java, enum-map

I was looking into Java EnumMap implementation and found that if I pass null value to EnumMap, EnumMap assign a Object class object in place of just null Value.

Code from EnumMap Class:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
        typeCheck(key);

        int index = key.ordinal();
        Object oldValue = vals[index];
        vals[index] = maskNull(value);
        if (oldValue == null)
            size++;
        return unmaskNull(oldValue);
}

private Object maskNull(Object value) {
        return (value == null ? NULL : value);
}

private static final Object NULL = new Object() {
            public int hashCode() {
                return 0;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "java.util.EnumMap.NULL";
            }
   };
```

My question is why java place a object in place of direct assigning a null value to given key. What kind of benefit java gets doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It allows to distinguish between keys which were never added to the map and ones that were added with `null` value. You can see this even in the code you quoted:

```
if (oldValue == null)
    size++;
```

If `null` was previously put into the map with this key, `oldValue` will be `NULL` and the size will not be changed.

Comment: To expand on this a little - it's a consequence of the fact that since the keys are Enums, the value store is a pre-allocated array of known size - all possible keys are directly mapped to values, there are no buckets and nothing can collide.  A tag value is needed to so the empty value elements can be distinguished from the ones where an explicit null was inserted.

Comment: And to expand on _that_, `null` is used for empty elements and `NULL` for `null` ones (rather than vice versa) because this way, newly allocated array immediately represents an empty map.